Excel function to generate series of rows based on item counts
I want to generate a list of items in column A based on the number for that row in column B. I am using column C as a helper column that is a cumulative sum of column B. Column D is where I want to generate the series of items in column A. Column D is currently using the formula:
=IF(ROW()-ROW($D$2)+1 <= MAX($C$2:$C$10), INDEX($A$2:$A$10, MATCH(ROW()-ROW($D$2)+1, $C$2:$C$10)))


I need to figure out why the first 2 rows always return #N/A and cut off the end of the series after reaching row 10.
Note - There will never be more than 4 different items in column A, so the formula will never have to evaluate A and B after row 5.
If you are familiar with SQL, I am essentially trying to do a reverse GROUP BY with COUNT(*).
I feel like I am very close to the solution but am missing something. Any insight on how to correct this output or a different approach would be appreciated.

Your formula is correct. This issue is with your helper row.  It should start with 1 and then add the previous rows column B value.  The last value should be 10.

As already mentioned by @RobertMearns Sir, start with 1 in the helper column and copy the following down for the rest of the cells. =C2+B2 and then enter the following formula in cell D2: =IF((ROW()-ROW($D$2)+1)<MAX($C$2:$C$5),INDEX($A$2:$A$4,MATCH((ROW()-ROW($D$2)+1),$C$2:$C$5,1)),"")

Also, there are multiple times these queries are raised one don't even need a helper column, if you intend to use helper then refer the last dupe post. it uses VLOOKUP()

With VLOOKUP() place the helper column in A --> =IF(ROW()>MAX($A$2:$A$5),"",VLOOKUP(ROW()-1,$A$2:$B$5,2,1))
